# Walkie Talkie without SIP

Tags: android, voip, microphone, codec

I am trying to do a kind of walkie talkie in android. I did using the classes audiorecord and audiotrack but these are not suitable to transmit the PCM data. I would like to use other codec like AMR which are less bandwith consuming. Can you tell me how to implement it, I mean which classes or method to convert PCM to other codec?

Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution for this one in Android, and you will have to bring your own.
Such a codec will usually run in the NDK, so some stitching using JNI will be required as well.

There should be several such libraries available - free and for a price.
Search google for AMR codec. Focus on those running on ARM CPUs or those that are specific to Android.

Comment: ok, You mean to encode PCM to ARM through NDK. Do not you think this can overload CPU?

Comment: It's PCM to AMR. And you don't really have a choice in the matter. The CPU will get used, but not overloaded. Android phones today have 1GHz and upwards which is more than enough for voice coding

Comment: Ok, what do you recommend, PCM to ARM in a java class or use NDK/JNI?

Comment: Again - it is not ARM but AMR. ARM is a chip architecture, AMR is a voice codec. Doing such conversions from PCM to AMR are better done in the NDK layer.